# Custom Annotation like Lombok

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

I want to implement a custom annotation which when used by other classes exposes two methods to them. Something like shown below:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface BaseEntity{
     public String toString(){ return "Hello" ;}
     public String toCustomString() { return "my hello";}
}
```

Now what I want is whenever any class uses the above annotation. It gets these methods exposed to it by default, something like what Lombok does when we use @Getter

```
@BaseEntity
public class Person{}
Person p = new Person();
p.toCustomString(); // this should work
```

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps use [Byte Buddy](https://bytebuddy.net/) or a [custom lombok annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-custom-annotation)?

Comment: You can always create your own Lombok Annotation Handler, but keep in mind that it's a little brittle and writing your own code would probably be less painful

Comment: Yes creating own Lombok Annotation Handler seemed brittle to me as well. So was wondering if there is an alternative way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

While not exactly what you asked, I think you can achieve what you want with a class hierarchy that takes advantage of the annotation:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)                                             
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)                                                       
public @interface BaseEntity {                                                  
    String string();                                                            
    String customString();                                                      
}                                                                               
                                                                                
public abstract class AbstractClass {                                           
    @Override                                                                   
    public String toString() {                                                  
        return getClass().getAnnotation(BaseEntity.class).string();             
    }                                                                           
                                                                                
    public String toCustomString() {                                            
        return getClass().getAnnotation(BaseEntity.class).customString();       
    }                                                                           
}
```

And then a concrete subclass:

```java
@BaseEntity(string = "Hello", customString = "my hello")                        
public class Example extends AbstractClass {                                    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {                   
        Example example = new Example();                                        
                                                                                
        System.out.println(example.toString());                                 
        System.out.println(example.toCustomString());                           
    }                                                                           
}
```

yields:

```sh
Hello                                                                           
my hello
```

In response to your comment, my real-world solution is to define an annotation and an interface with default methods (which makes a `toString()` implementation problematic):

```java
@BaseEntity(customString = "my hello")                                          
public class Example implements BaseEntityAnnotated {                           
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {                   
        Example example = new Example();                                        
                                                                                
        System.out.println(example.toCustomString());                           
    }                                                                           
}                                                                               
                                                                                
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)                                             
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)                                                       
public @interface BaseEntity {                                                  
    String customString();                                                      
}                                                                               
                                                                                
public interface BaseEntityAnnotated {                                          
    default String toCustomString() {                                           
        return this.getClass().getAnnotation(BaseEntity.class).customString();  
    }                                                                           
}
```

I then implement a [`Processor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) that enforces an entity annotated with `BaseEntity` must also implement `BaseEntityAnnotated`.

I have examples at [`AntTask`](https://repo.hcf.dev/javadoc/ball-api/20200622.0/ball/util/ant/taskdefs/AntTask.html), [`AnnotatedAntTask.getAntTaskName()`](https://repo.hcf.dev/javadoc/ball-api/20200622.0/ball/util/ant/taskdefs/AnnotatedAntTask.html#getAntTaskName--), and [AntTaskProcessor](https://repo.hcf.dev/javadoc/ball-api/20200622.0/ball/annotation/processing/AntTaskProcessor.html).

Comment: But I want to avoid extending class for this since Java allows to extend only one class. Otherwise, I could have directly extended BaseEntity.

Comment: Again I would directly implement the interface and not use the annotation at all.

Comment: OK.   I'm not sure how to help except to say I concur with the comments that writing something similar to a Lombok handler to generate code will likely be brittle and painful

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an annotation processing class (which must be a subclass of `javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor`) to actually add the code into the `Person` class.

See: http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101

Comment: I checked the code at this link but what I want to do is add method definition from another class to Person class. Not sure how we can achieve it

Comment: Lombok uses internal javac apis.

Comment: True. So any suggestions on how I can achieve the same? Maybe have an interface with a default implementation?